# While coding for a solution to a question of Primality Test, my code was not being processed in the vs code

Tags: c++, runtime-error

The Question:
Alice and Bob are meeting after a long time. As usual they love to play some math games. This times Alice takes the call and decides the game. The game is very simple, Alice says out an integer and Bob has to say whether the number is prime or not. Bob as usual knows the logic but since Alice doesn't give Bob much time to think, so Bob decides to write a computer program.

Help Bob accomplish this task by writing a computer program which will calculate whether the number is prime or not .

My code:
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime (int n)
 {
     if (n==1)
     {
         return false;
     }
     for (int i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
     {
         if (n % i == 0)
         {
             return false;
         }
     }  
     return true;
 }
 int main ()
 {
     int t,n;
     cin>>t;
     while (t--)
     {
         cin>>n;
         if (isPrime(n))
         {
         cout<<"yes"<<endl;
         }
         else
         {
             cout<<"no"<<endl;
         }
     }
    
 }
```

Comment: What does it mean: "not being processed"?

Comment: Please don't spam tags

Comment: Can you get a "HelloWorld" processed?

Comment: If you insert a `cout<<"Please enter a number: "<<endl;` at the start of `main()`, does it give you output?

Comment: Your call path looks weird. What if you move the `"`?

Comment: What is your method of providing input to the program? It does not look like you entered numbers, which I think the program requires. You did abort execution after 3 seconds of seeing no output, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your method of calling your program succeeds for a HelloWorld example...

Executing your program will not give any visible output before it is necessary to input numbers. Even if this is required behaviour, you could check by inserting a prompt output before the first needed input.

You might change that by calling your program like `echo 3 2 1 0 | .\primal`.
Or by calling the created executable directly from a prompt and interactively entering numbers.